# tumblr api v2, get posts return 404 Not found

Tags: ajax, api, tumblr, posts

I just discover the tumblr API (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2)

I have created a new blog (protected with password) and also generated an API_KEY.

Here is my ajax request :

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url : "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog-dev/posts/photo?api_key=MYAPIKEY",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

And the result is :

```
{"meta":{"status":404,"msg":"Not Found"},"response":[]}
```

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong, what am I missing ?!

Comment: iirc, you can't access a password protect blog via the api. I can't find anything to back this up, but I would try taking the password off and seeing if the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/`**`{$blogname}`**`.tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=`**`{$public_consumer_key}`**

This works for me, try updating your code from what you have, to this.

Obviously replace `{$blogname}` with the blog name that has been authenticated with your application that you are trying to access, and obviously replace `{$public_consumer_key}` with your registered applications' *public* consumer key.